# Dynamically calling variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops, variables

In Angular Component, I want to use different variables.
Ex:

```
export class AppComponent{
 value1;
 value2;
 value3;
 value4;
  
 print(position)
 {
   console.log(this.('value'+position));  
 //position will have values like 1,2,3,4 and I want to access value1, value2,value3,value4 
 //variables accordingly.
 }
  
}
```

How to execute this?

Comment: `this['value'+position]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.value1 = "val1";
        this.value2 = "val2";
        this.value3 = "val3";
        this.value4 = "val4";
    }

    print(position) {
        console.log(this['value' + position]);
    }
}

appComponent = new AppComponent();

appComponent.print(4);
```

```
class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.value1 = "val1";
        this.value2 = "val2";
        this.value3 = "val3";
        this.value4 = "val4";
    }

    print(position) {
        console.log(this['value' + position]);
    }
}

appComponent = new AppComponent();

appComponent.print(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's achived with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names):

```js
export class AppComponent{
   value1;
   value2;
   value3;
   value4;
  
   print(position)
   {
       console.log(this['value' + position]);
       // or with template literals
       // console.log(this[`value${position}`]); 
   }
}
```

[Template literals documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you very much, it saved my hell of a time. I was searching about it from more than an hour and couldn't get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the reference from dot notation to square brackets notation and you will achieve what you wish for.

```
export class AppComponent {
  value1 = 1;
  value2 = 2;
  value3 = 3;
  value4 = 4;

  constructor() {
    this.print(3); // will print 3
  }
  
  print(position: number): void {
    console.log(this[`value${position}`]);  
  }
}
```